# How to use fs.readStream and fs.writesream to send and recieve Video ( .mp4 ) files [from client to server or vice versa ] [in Node Js]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream, video-streaming

```js
   ## Here is my Unsucessfull approach  ##


----------


> Server side code
> Recieve Video stream from client and save it in .mp4 format

var express = require('express');
var app = global.app = exports.app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.post('/video_main', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req)
  const video_stream = fs.createWriteStream('vde.mp4')
  req.pipe(video_stream)
  //save the video stream to vde.mp4
})


app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {

  return res.status(404).json({
    'status': 'FAILURE',
    'message': 'Not found'
  })

})

app.listen('3000');
// server listening on http://localhost:3000/


----------


> Client side  code
> send video stream to server

const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
var readablestream = fs.createReadStream('SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4')
const write = fs.createWriteStream('test.mp4');
const r = request.post("http://localhost:3000/video_main");
r.pipe(readablestream);

/*

*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error with your code is on the client side the last line should be

```
readablestream.pipe(r);
```

Since you are piping the data from the readablestream into the request.

For future reference you should always follow the convention:

```
readstream.pipe(writestream);
```

> I figured this out by analyzing the code on this github, which has
>   pretty nice implementation of file transfer over html:
>
> https://gist.github.com/alepez/9205394